# "Error Saving View" - Personal View In Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

We have created one `personal view` on our custom list.

This is simple view with some columns. No Sort or Filter setting is configured in view setting.  we are applying filter/sort through List View UI.

But when we sort or filter any column and then click on "SAVE THIS VIEW", we got error "`Error Saving View`".

[image: See Screenshot]

Note: We can able to save public views. Problem only happens with personal view.

Comment: is this happening only in modern list experience?

Comment: No. It's classic mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue so what I did was

- list settings
- Scroll down to Views
- Select your personal veiew
- scroll down to filters
- Select Show items only when the following is true
- Select the filters you want to show
- Click OK

my personal view was saved with filters of my choice.